# Recording screen activities

Tags: android

I have a requirement in my app recording screen activities as a video file. i am new to android i dont know whether it is possible or not in andorid. if possible please suggest me a way to do that thanks in advance

Comment: http://www.deskshare.com/screen-recorder.aspx

Comment: i am searching for the relevent answer since so many days but got no luck please help me to do in programatically in my activity i dont know it is possible or not

Answer (score 0):

personally i used ViewletCam on windows. It's free!
http://download.cnet.com/ViewletCam/3000-2075_4-10290391.html